# Use function return value without storing it first - why is this rarely seen?

Tags: c, syntax, return-value, function-call

It seems to be uncommon to immediately use the return value of a function directly, without storing it in a variable first (i.e. `foo()->bar` where `foo()` returns a pointer to a struct with member `bar`.  All compilers I've tried seem to allow this, but I rarely see it in "the wild".  Is there a reason this is rarely used in pure C, other than the fact that you might want to check the return value first, and assuming you have an appropriate way of freeing the memory at a later time?

A more explicit example:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

struct FooBar {
    int bar;
} FooBar;

struct FooBar *foo(void)
{
    struct FooBar *test = malloc(sizeof(*test));
    test->bar = 42;
    return test;
}    

int main (void)
{
    printf("%d\n", foo()->bar);
    return 1;
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(FooBar)`  --> `sizeof(*test)`

Comment: Memory leak. If you don't store the return of `malloc()`, how could you `free()` it? C is not automatically garbage-collected.

Comment: To expand on @SouravGhosh's comment, `sizeof(FooBar)` is perfectly correct in that context, but `sizeof(*test)` (or `sizeof *test)` is more robust. If the type of the pointer changes, the `sizeof(*test)` remains correct.

Comment: Developers who don't store function results, (and other stuff), into intermediate/temp vars are the ones who continually post here complaining 'Fix my code, I cannot find what is wrong'.   They are not good enough developers to understand that ease of debugging is MUCH more important than economising on a line of code.

Answer (score 1):

As per your code

```
 foo()->bar
```

is possible but not used, because, in case `foo()` returns a NULL pointer (possibly to indicate some sort of failure), you'll invoke [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Taking the reverse angle, if the usage is direct dereference, then your function MUST NOT return any invalid pointer. This makes the function less *robust* and *modular*.

OTOH, in case you store the return value of the function in a variable, then you can perform a NULL check on the variable (carrying the `return`ed pointer), and then go ahead with the dereference.

To clear things up a bit, there is nothing in the C standard that prevents you from doing the direct dereference, but any decent coding guidelines will disallow (or, discourage, at least) to do so.

Comment: well, this would be a case that one would want to check the return value before using it. And that is mentioned by the OP.

Comment: Quoting from the question. *Is there a reason this is rarely used in pure C, **other than the fact that you might want to check the return value first before using it?***

Comment: @Haris and I replied with _why_ part. :)

Answer (score 0):

> It seems to be uncommon to immediately use the return value of a function directly, without storing it in a variable first

True, that reflects good programming practice to check the return value.  Many functions return an error condition by using special values like `NULL`, `-1`, `EOF`.

Common examples where the return value is not used nor checked are output functions.

Common examples where the return value is used yet not checked are `str...()` functions where the return value is a copy of the input.

```
return strcpy(dest, src);
```

---

With good code, to dereference a pointer return value from a function without saving the pointer implies:

```
bar(foo()->field);
```

1. Return value of `foo()` is not `NULL`.
2. The other fields are not of interest.
3. House-keeping on the return value is not needed, like `free()`, `fclose()`.

This set of conditions is not common in user code.

---

When a function returns a pointer, it is good coding practice to check for errors before de-referencing the pointer as often a `NULL` return indicates some issue.  If the function may have allocated data, the check is crucial.

```
FILE *istream = fopen(filename, "r");
if (istream == NULL) ...
else { 
  foo(istream); 
  fclose(istream);
}

struct tm *tm = localtime(&t);
if (tm ! NULL) {
  printf("Year %d\n", tm->tm_year + 1900);
}
```

When a function returns a non-pointer, the need is less critical but still wise.

```
int cnt = fscanf(istream, "%d", &value);
if (cnt == 1) foo(value);
```

Some functions rarely have their return value checked.

```
printf("Hello World\n");  // return value not checked.
```

Answer (score 0):

There are three primary reasons why you want to store a return value into a separate variable as opposed to using it directly:

- It allows you to perform sanity checks on the returned value before use - `NULL` checks, range checks (say for an array index), check for empty strings, etc.;

  It makes debugging easier - you can more easily examine the return value in a debugger, and you can more easily log those values; also, if one a function is throwing a segfault, you can more easily determine exactly which function it is;

  It makes maintenance easier - code like

  ```
  x = f(); 
  y = g(); 
  z = h(x, y);
  printf( "z = %d\n", z );
  ```

  is a bit easier to understand and maintain than code like

  ```
   printf("z = %d\n", h(f(),g()));
  ```

I'm sure people can come up with other reasons, but those are the big three for me.